# How to control AVPlayer buffering

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm using an `AVPlayer` to play a remote progressive download (i.e. non-HLS) video. But, I can't figure out how to control its buffering behavior.

I would like to pre-fetch 2 seconds of the video before it's ready to play, and also to stop buffering when the video is paused.

Here's my setup:

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let player = AVPlayer()
```

I tried the following, without success:

```
// doesn't start buffering
playerItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = 2.0
```

```
// doesn't stop buffering
playerItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = 2.0
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
```

I tried `player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = true` in both cases, and in combination with various `player.pause()` or `player.rate = 0` - doesn't work.

A potential approach that comes to mind is to observe for `loadedTimeRanges` until the first 2 seconds loaded and set current item of the player to `nil`.

```
let c = playerItem.publisher(for: \.loadedTimeRanges, options: .new)
                  .compactMap { $0.first as? CMTimeRange }
                  .sink { 
                      if $0.duration.seconds - $0.start.seconds > 2 {
                         player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)

                      }
                  }
```

This would work for pre-buffer, but it **doesn't work for pausing**, because it makes the video blank instead of paused. (And at this point, I feel I'm attempting to reimplement/interfere with some core buffering functionality)